# How do I search through an array?

Tags: c, arrays, database, loops

For my assignment I have to create a structure that allows the user to enter student info (ID, DOB, & Phone number). I have no problem doing this that is quite simple. Now I need to search through that enter info using the student ID to display that students corresponding DOB and phone number, this is the problem that I am having trouble working with. If you see any other problems with my program please let me know what is wrong and why I should change so I can learn from my mistakes.

I'm also not sure how to store all these different parts of the students info to an array and have them correspond to each other. So when I search an ID how does it know to return the correct DOB and phone. I'm really lost here guys and needing some help. What ever you tell me or if you give me code, please explain why I should be doing what you're telling me to do.

NOTE: All my classes are online so getting hold of my professor for help is a challenge, so I've turn to you guys for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct infoStruct 
{
    int studentID;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int phone;
    int end;
};

int main (void)
{
    int students = 0;   
    int infoArray [students];
    struct infoStruct info;
    int studentID;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int phone;
    int end;



    while (info.end != -1) {
        students = students + 1;
        printf("Enter student information (ID, day, month, year, phone)\n");
        printf("Enter -1 following the phone number to end the process to continue enter 0\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &info.studentID, &info.day, &info.month, &info.year, &info.phone, &info.end);
    }
    if (info.end = -1){
        printf("You entered %d student(s)\n", students);
    }
    //Student Search
    printf("Please enter the student ID of the student your looking for\n.");
    scanf("%d", info.studentID);
    printf(" DOB: %d %d %d, Phone: %d", info.month, info.day, info.year, info.phone);

}
```

Comment: well you can use that infoArray, but make its type infoStruct, not sure if it is just typo but do not you missing some parentheses around your definition of struct? When you have that array then you can easy loop through it...

Comment: @DusanPlavak So it would be infoStruct infoArray [students]; ?

Comment: Please read a C tutorial before writing C code. The code does look like you didn't read one.

Comment: Also, what you could do is try to actually understand what people are telling you here, instead of just asking the same question again (like you did!) and waiting for someone to give you the code you can copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

i need to read better want you want to do, however, to simplify your code for you, and for who read it, don't write everything in your main and separate in functions. After that you can call that functions and, with their names, program understanding will be increased.

Comment: try to create an function called searchStudent(...). Firstly you need to know the size of your array to create a for loop. Now, you will ask the user for your student id. During the for cycle, you will compare the id selected with each id students of array. When you find the student id you want, print what you want in that position if the array. I hope i could help

Comment: How do I store the user input into the array?

Comment: For example, 
printf("Isert id: "); scanf("%d", &x); After that, you select your position and you'll do nameOfStruct[position].id=x; with this, you are writting what you have in x, in id parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you need to search through infoArray using the student ID.
First of all, I think you want your array to be of type `infoStruct` (which represents the students). `students` is the number of elements of the array.

```
//storing the student info
for (int i=0;i<students;++i)
{
  scanf("%d %d[...]",&infoArray[i].studentID, &infoArray[i].year[...]);
}
```

Let's say you are searching for the student whose ID is, for example, called id1.
You would do that like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<students;++i)
{
  if (infoArray[i].studentID==id1)
  printf("%d",infoArray[i].phone);
}
```

I'm not really sure I understood your question well, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to notice...

You initialize `students = 0` and then set the size of an array of integers called `infoArray` to 0. That is what `int infoArray[students]` does.

Next, you don't need to initialize every element in the struct, because that is what the struct is for. Simply saying `struct infoStruct info;` should do the trick. Don't forget if you were using a pointer (i.e. `struct infoStruct *info`) you would need to use malloc to allocate the memory for that struct.

However, to set up an array of structs it is 1 simple line of code:
`struct infoStruct info[x]` x being how big you wish to make the array. Keep in mind if you set x equal to 0 like you did above and tried to add an element to the array you would get a segFault as the memory has not been allocated for it.

Lastly, you can now search through that array with a for loop.

Comment: @user2172993 not a problem. If the answer is right, please click the check mark next to it. :)