# How do you assign values entered in a structure to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, structure

I'm having a little trouble doing this. I'm creating a program that will store individuals information by ID number using a structure. I need to store then in an array then search through it with a for loop (easy). Whenever I try to compile I get an error saying request for member "blah blah" in something not a structure or union.

I'm getting this error for the final printf statement.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct infoStruct  
{
  int studentID;
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
  int phone;
  int end;
};

int main (void)
{
  int students = 0;

struct infoStruct *info = NULL;

  while (info.end != -1) {
    students = students + 1;
    printf("Enter student information (ID, day, month, year, phone)\n");
    printf("Enter -1 following the phone number to end the process to continue enter 0\n");
    info = malloc(sizeof(struct infoStruct) * students);
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &info.studentID, &info.day, &info.month, &info.year, &info.phone, &info.end);
  }

  printf("You entered %d student(s)\n", students);

  printf("Enter Student ID\n"); 
  scanf("%d", info.studentID); 

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I search through an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861822/how-do-i-search-through-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

First, your array should be of type `infoStruct`.
You should know the value of `students`. Then you can do something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<students;++i)
{
  scanf(%d %d"[...],&infoArray[i].studentID, &infoArray[i].year[...]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
int students = 0;
...
int infoArray [students];
...
while()
{
  students = students + 1;
  ...
}
```

Will not work. You have to declare the size of your array *a priori* and it can't change during run-time without **explicitly** reallocating it.

What you can do is:

```
printf("What's the number of students you want?\n");
scanf("%d", &students);
...
int infoArray [students];
...
while(i++ < students)
{
  // collect the data...
  ...
}
```

Since you can't change the size of the array dynamically in C without **explicitly** reallocating it, you will have to go for a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) solution if you want a dynamic solution.

Comment: Yes, but this feature would have to be implemented. Simply calling infoArray[students++] won't do the job.

Comment: Nope , need to reallocate , init then access it with ++; I just pointed you giving wrong info , size of an array can be changed both way extended or shrinked , no need to say "size of an array can't be changed dynamically in c" since it is false.

Answer (score 1):

`infoArray` is declared a `int`. It does not provide structure elements like
`infoArray.studentID`. That causes the compiler to complain *... something not a structure or union.*

`infoArray [students];` with `int students = 0;` is questionable too.

You'd get (rewritten to suit the need. However, with some open questions):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STUDENTS 200

typedef struct {
  int studentID;
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
  int phone;
  int end;
} info_TYPE;

int main (void)
{
  info_TYPE infoArray [MAX_STUDENTS];
  int students = 0;

  while (infoArray[students].end != -1) {
    printf("Enter student information (ID, day, month, year, phone)\n");
    printf("Enter -1 following the phone number to end the process to continue enter 0\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &infoArray[students].studentID, &infoArray[students].day, &infoArray[students].month, &infoArray[students].year, &infoArray[students].phone, &infoArray[students].end);
    students = students + 1;
    if (students >= MAX_STUDENTS) break;
  }
  if (infoArray[students - 1].end = -1) printf("You entered %d student(s)\n", students);

  printf("Enter Student ID", infoArray[students - 1].studentID); 
  // no idea what this line was for, presumably another previous attempt.
  scanf("%d", infoArray[students - 1].studentID); 
  // getting tired to follow the speed at which the question is modified, presumably last edit here!
}
```

Comment: This didn't really help me because I still need to store the info entered into an array. So when I do this trying to use malloc i get an error telling me studentID is something not of a structure or union.

Comment: @user2172993: I've modified the code that results are stored in infoArray.

Comment: Anyway info[students] is out of bounds , if you want to access last cell of this array use info[students-1] since arrays in c starts ftom 0. What you would to do is to run on for(I=0 ;I<students;I++) , and the assign the input in to info[I]

Comment: Also I suggest to use tupedef struct it will be easier :)

Comment: You should start from students =1; also ur first assignment is before allocating array will result in crash. Start with student =1 ; allocate it , get input and then reallocate it using realoc function(if you need to add more students) . That's it simple

Comment: Yes but I see you still not allocating the array before first assignment , you can not scanf in to unallocated array since it is pointer to nowhere.

Comment: Oh I see you done it of size max students , sorry my fault I thought it should be dynamic array ))

Comment: 1 more thing in ur while u should check if students < max_students otherwise u can go out of bounds if some1 will enter 201 students.

Comment: @user2533527: See code: `if (students >= MAX_STUDENTS) break;`. Wake up! This is it for this question.

Comment: Woke up, u done it after the scanf -> so first you crash then you check .

Answer (score 1):

"info" is a pointer. So to access its values you should unreference it. As you are using array of struct you can do it in the following way:

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &info[some_counter].studentID, &info[some_counter].day, &info[some_counter].month, &info[some_counter].year, &info[come_counter].phone, &info[come_counter].end);
```

Also it is better to use realloc() call to change size of array of structs and fix in some way end of loop condition. Now it makes a crash because info is NULL and right before start you are trying to dereference this NULL pointer.

Loop with realloc() may look like following code:

```
  while (true) {
    printf("Enter student information (ID, day, month, year, phone)\n");
    printf("To finish enter word \"end\"\n");

    struct infoStruct *new_info = realloc(info, (students+1)*sizeof(struct infoStruct));
    if (new_info == NULL) {
      printf("Out of memory! errno = %s\n", strerror(errno));
      break;
    } else {
      info = new_info;
    }
    result = scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", 
        &info[students].studentID,
        &info[students].day, 
        &info[students].month, 
        &info[students].year, 
        &info[students].phone, 
        &info[students].end
                  );

    if (result != 6) {
      students--;
      info = realloc(info, sizeof(struct infoStruct) * students);
      break;
    }

    students++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because

printf("Enter Student ID", infoArray.studentID);

treats infoArray.studentID as a structure member, which it is not.